# how do I make an iframe from an external url responsive on my site?

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I've seen solutions for this regarding videos, none of which worked. The iframe I am pulling in is of real estate properties and although my site is responsive the iframe is not. My site is a Wordpress site.

Here is the code I've got in place at the moment:

```
.property {
position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.property iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

So I have the iframe inside a div with a class called 'property'. It is my understanding that the iframe should expand and contract with the width of the wrapper div 'property' but this doesn't seem to be the case. I'm happy to provide the url if needed.

Comment: Try after adding max-width: 100%; in ".property iframe"

Comment: Resizing the iframe element itself won’t necessarily mean that the content inside it will automatically do the same thing …

Comment: No that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Fitvid.js does work with iframes. 
http://fitvidsjs.com/

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selector").fitVids();
  });
</script>
```

You need jQuery for this to work. Place it in you `<head>` after the CSS

Comment: Thanks, I'm not really familiar with JQuery, I'm struggling to implement this. I've worked through the notes on the fitvids site but it's not working.

Comment: Do you have a link for your development? Basically you need to have jQuery, fitvids and then the fitvids function call.

Comment: Please forgive my newbness about this, I really appreciate your help. I've downloaded the fitvids js and uploaded to my root. I've used the Google source for jquery. Ive put this into my header.

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Target your .container, .wrapper, .post, etc.
    $("#thing-with-videos").fitVids();
  });
</script>

Comment: It would be better if this is online somewhere. Please edit your question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I never found the solution to this that I wanted, I'm sure fitvids works but I don't understand JQuery enough to implement it. I did however pick a different feed for the iframe from another source and it works (resizes). Thanks for all the suggestions.